# TypeScript Class exported as a UMD module with strict mode

Tags: typescript, strict, umd

Is there a way I can have a TypeScript class exported as a UMD module with strict mode enabled? The "gotcha" is the strict mode part.

My code looks something like:

```
class Foo {
    bar(): Foo.Bam {}
}

namespace Foo {
    export function boom() {}
    export interface Bam {}
}

export = Foo;
```

Elsewhere the module can be used like:

```
import * as Foo from 'my-module';

var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar()

Foo.boom();

interface Kaboom extends Foo.Bam {}
```

I want strict mode to apply to all of `Foo`, but not to the entire script, as it may be concat with other unknown scripts.

A definition file is also being generated.

I can just wrap everything in a closure during the build process, but I'm looking for a pre-compilation solution first.

***Edit:***

Added more details to my question, just in case someone finds a way in the future.

I ended up just adding a simple post-compile fix. After the UMD module is generated. I replace this line:

```
})(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
```

With this line:

```
})(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {"use strict";
```

Now everything inside the module is strict, and the script itself is not.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://pastee.org/kzp82 ? (I put the code to http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground)

Comment: Nope, it needs to be exported using `--module umd`, thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fixed issue. See [Change prologue emit location to inside module IIFEs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5116).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your modules in the standard way (i.e. loading them as you need them) you can add it to the top of your file - the statement will be scoped to the file.

```
"use strict"

class Foo {
    bar() {}
}

namespace Foo {
    export function bar() {}
}

export = Foo;
```

If you are actually combining your output into a single file, you can't limit the scope of the statement without introducing namespaces (aside: I'm not a fan of internal modules / namespaces).

```
namespace Example {
    "use strict"

    export class Foo {
        bar() {}
    }
}

namespace Foo {
    export function bar() {}
}

export = Example.Foo;
```

Comment: There’s no problem when it’s lazy loaded. However, when the module is bundled together with other modules for production use (requirejs), I don’t want strict mode just hanging out there. The module will be publically available so I’m just trying to cover my bases. Your second option of adding another namespace works until I try to generate a definition file; error TS4082. I ended up just implementing the build script fix, but I’ll update my question with the details. Thanks :)